# when hover over the table the checkBoxes move to left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

Ive mvc application with table with 4 properties ,I use the functionality of hovering the table
to display some buttons ,when I hover the table I see the buttons but all the check-boxes are 
moving bit left closer to the name property,there is a way to avoid that the moving of the checkboxes
when hovering the table

This is the table

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    @* Button for adding some user *@
    <div class="text-right">
        <a href="#" id="addRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> new</a>
    </div>



    @* List of users *@
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox1)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox2)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.checkBox3)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody id="dataTable">
            <tr id="emptyRow" style="display: none;">
                <td>@Html.TextBox("name")</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox2")</td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox3")</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="actions-default" style="display:none;">
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = -1 }, new { @class = "btn-edit" }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = -1 }, new { @class = "btn-delete" })
                    </span>
                    <span class="actions-editable">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default btn-create" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" />
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr data-id="@item.Id">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox1)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox2)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.checkBox3)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="actions-default">
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn-edit" }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn-delete" })
                        </span>
                        <span class="actions-editable" style="display:none;">
                            <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default btn-update" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" />
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

And this is the css code for hover the table

```
#dataTable .actions-default {
    display: none;
}

#dataTable:hover .actions-default {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle with the html in output?

Answer (score 0):

Set display inline-block

**CSS**

```
#dataTable .actions-default {
    display: inline-block;
}

#dataTable:hover .actions-default {
   /* Set color text, background color...whatever */
   color: red; /* example */
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/HuPpD/1/)**

Comment: I tried it and noting was changed the same problem exist...Btw the fiddler which have send is not working .noting happen...

Comment: Sorry it was other fiddle, i correct the bug..now is pointing to the right one

Answer (score 0):

This can be because when you show your buttons the table cell becomes wider, so every other column adjust their size to match your container  width.

Try to give a width to your columns

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the span is an inline elmement, the hover style should look like this to better control of the element:

```
#dataTable:hover .actions-default {
    display: inline;
}
```